# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia working just with localhost.it is not working with ip address

Tags: node.js, getusermedia

**My script.js file**
[error pictuer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTx6L.png)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oL1r.png)

Comment: Outside localhost, your website needs to be secured(running on https) to use navigator.mediaDevices.

Comment: please, do not use screen captures to show code, data, logs, and all that. Put in the text.  Indent it four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

getUserMedia() only works from localhost and https origin servers. You cannot use it with http sites. Because cybercreeps.

Seriously, the browser security people think it's an awful idea to allow http sites to switch on video or audio. It would be too easy for bad actors to spy on us by corrupting legitimate websites.

That doesn't mean developing and testing with https is any less a pain in the xxx neck. But you can use nodejs's `https` class in place of the `http` class to serve your gUM javascript.

Other development-grade web servers can also serve https.